# python converting dict to JSON

Tags: python

I have a python dict in the following format

```
{'status': ['Done'], 'urgency': 1, 'text': {'shorttext': 'Short Text', 'longtext': 'Long Text'}, 'startdate': '2019-03-03', 'enddate': '2019-03-03'}
```

which when I convert to json using json_dumps

```
obj=json_dumps(dict)
print(obj)

'{"status": ["Done"], "urgency": 1, "text": {"shorttext": "Short Text", "longtext": "Long Text"}, "startdate": "2019-03-03", "enddate": "2019-03-03"}'
```

Now when I try to post this payload to an api using request.post call in the format below

```
requests.post(url, headers, json=obj)
```

I get the below error

```
no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value (\'{"status": ["Done"], "urgency": 1, "text": {"shorttext": "Short Text", "longtext": "Long Text"}, "startdate": "2019-03-03", "enddate": "2019-03-03"}'\)
```

Any inputs on what might be causing this? I suspect is the '' the payload is enclosed in, but am not completely sure.
Thanks!

Comment: You are posting the string instead of the dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't dump the the dict!

```
requests.post(url, headers, json=dict)
```

Or, if you have to:

```
requests.post(url, headers, data=obj)
```

Comment: you beat me to it. Well done, I have removed my answer